# Редирект с http://site.ru/ на http://site.ru

Tags: mod_rewrite

Здравствуйте

Нужно настроить редирект с http://site.ru/ на http://site.ru

Текущий файл .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.(.*)  [NC]      
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/(.+)/$  
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^news/?$ index.php?module=news [L]  
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=news&id=$1 [L]  
RewriteRule ^contacts/?$ index.php?module=contacts [L]  
RewriteRule ^registration/?$ index.php?module=registration [L]
RewriteRule ^clients/?$ index.php?module=clients [L]
```

с точки зрения ПС http://site.ru/ и http://site.ru это разные страницы, я хочу избавиться от дублей

Comment: проверьте формулировку вопроса. Откуда и куда?

Comment: @zhenyab, ТС хочет избавиться от слэша, как я понял. )

Comment: что за бред? :)))

Comment: thunder, с точки зрения ПС http://site.ru/ и http://site.ru это разные страницы, я хочу избавиться от дублей

Comment: ?? это у кого такие странные взгляды на сайт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [протоколе http](http://www.lib.ru/WEBMASTER/rfc2068/section-5.html#p1-2) [не предусмотрен](http://www.lib.ru/WEBMASTER/rfc2068/section-5.html#p1-2) механизм получения страниц путь к которым не начинается на / (скорее предусмотрен, но явно запрещен) 
для примера:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET a HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
Host: localhost

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 27 Aug 2013 23:23:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Debian)
Content-Length: 300
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

то-же самое если попытаться выполнить

```
GET HTTP/1.1
```

цитата из перевода rfc:

> Обратите внимание, что **абсолютный** путь **не может быть пустым**; если оригинальный URI пуст, то он ДОЛЖЕН запрашиваться как "/" (корневой каталог сервера).